Dfrobot INA219 incorrect reading open circuit voltage
So this sensor is a part of my MPPT project recently i built. This sensor is only making incorrect reading/measuring when i use dfrobot_ina219 library. If i use Adafruit library, then it can read correctly, now the problem is adafruit lib gives me a wrong current value. I measured the current flow using multimeter, the meter read 2,2Amp but sensor read 0,26amp.


